# How to run powershell script using c#

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run powershell script , but no success. I have powershell script in C:\ drive . This script accepts UserCredentials and one Export path as user input.
When i try to run this script on commandline , it prompts for exportpath and creds.

Below is what i am trying.

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("C:\\ex.ps1");
        pipeline.Commands.AddParameter(ExportPath", "C://");

       SecureString password = new SecureString();
       string str_password = "";
       string username = "";
       foreach (char x in str_password) { password.AppendChar(x); }
       PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(username, password);
       shell.Commands.AddParameter("Credential", credential);

       pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
       Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
       runspace.Close();
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not compile.

Comment: Can you post the corrected code ?

Comment: That's your job. `pipeline.Commands.AddParameter(ExportPath", "C://");` does not compile. Please post an actual reproducible example.